# Do DotA 2 heroes have the same "fun" names as in WC3 DotA?

Tags: dota-2, dota

In WC3 DotA, you would occasionally (1 out of 10 times) get little fun nicknames for your hero instead of their actual name (for instance, Puck!! for Puck, Clinkz Eastwood for Clinkz, YaphetS for Shadow Fiend, etc).

My question is, is this feature part of DotA 2?  If not, is anyone aware if Valve plans to add those names, or are some of them copyrighted by Blizzard?

Comment: Hey, Alec.  Unfortunately, I doubt we'd be able to answer the second question; that's speculation of the future of the industry, which is off-topic.  The first one, though, should be easily answerable.

Comment: Hi, fbueckert.  It might at first appear to be speculation, however if a company **explicitly** mentions that they are planning to do or implement a feature, then I would expect asking about their answer to not be speculation or off-topic.  Thoughts?

Comment: That's the thing, Alec; without that *exact* information, from the company, we can't prove **or** disprove it.  Kind of hard to prove a negative in cases like that.  That's exactly why those types of questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dota 2 heroes do not have "fun" names - picking a hero will give you a unit with their regular name.

Since the game is still in closed beta, I can not say with 100% certainty whether or not fun names will be added later, but I do recall a few of the names used in the past (I believe Kimahri might've been a nickname of Phantom Lancer?) are probably copyrighted by their respective source's companies.